# Detect when NSScrollView can be scrolled

Tags: objective-c, nstextview, nsscrollview

How can I detect when there is more text than is showing in NSScrollView?

I have tried various forms of this:

```objc
if (self.scrollView.contentSize.height > self.scrollView.bounds.size.height) {
    NSLog (@"Can be scrolled.");
}
```

".contentSize" and ".bounds" always have the same dimensions.

Comment: Compare `documentVisibleRect` and `documentView.bounds`?

Comment: They always have the same dimensions as well.

Comment: Can you scroll?

Comment: Yes, that is the bizarre part.

Comment: Have you tied comparing `scrollView.contentSize` & `scrollView. documentVisibleRect`?

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Kamil.S aren't `scrollView.contentSize` and `scrollView. documentVisibleRect .size` always the same?